# Expression is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got this error message for my PLSQL code:

```
expression 'V_EMPRECORD' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement.
```

Just don't know where it went wrong.
I'm required to Write a block of PL/SQL code which will do the following:

1 Create a cursor called emp_cur which will read the all rows from the    emp_tbl where the salary is greater than 70000.
2 Open the cursor
3 Fetch the information into the cursor
4 Display the Emplyees' details to the screen
5 Close the cursor

```
DECLARE
  TYPE v_empRecord IS RECORD(
    vFName emp_tbl.first_name%TYPE,
    vLName emp_tbl.last_name%TYPE,
    vSalary emp_tbl.salary%TYPE,
    vDept emp_tbl.department%Type);

  CURSOR c_empDetails IS
    SELECT * FROM emp_tbl
    WHERE salary > 70000;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_empDetails;
  FETCH c_empDetails INTO v_empRecord;
  CLOSE c_empDetails;
END;
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to fetch directly into a type.  You need to define an object of the type v_empRecord, then fetch into that.

I think you would find a cursor for loop much easier.  See the CURSOR FOR LOOP example here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CHDBJBJE

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend the answer to @Gary, I've got the same error eventhough I am using `INTO` with record type as `v_empRecord`. It was cause by silyy mistake as mentioned below

I am using the RECORD name next to `into` instead of creating a new variable with that record type

```
TYPE V_EMPRECORD
IS
RECORD
(
 ID NUMBER,
 NAME VARCHAR2(100),
 JOIN_DATE VARCHAR2(50)
);
EMP V_EMPRECORD; --DECLARE THE VARIABLE OF TYPE V_EMPRECORD
----- WRONG WAY
 SELECT.... INTO V_EMPRECORD FROM ...
----- RIGHT WAY
 SELECT .... INTO EMP FROM.....
```

Hope if you did the same mistake, this answer might will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE
  //define a record type
  TYPE v_empRecord_type IS RECORD(
    vFName emp_tbl.first_name%TYPE,
    vLName emp_tbl.last_name%TYPE,
    vSalary emp_tbl.salary%TYPE,
    vDept emp_tbl.department%Type);

  CURSOR c_empDetails IS
    SELECT * FROM emp_tbl
    WHERE salary > 70000;

  //define a record object belongs to the record type you defined before
  v_empRecord v_empRecord_type ;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_empDetails;
  FETCH c_empDetails INTO v_empRecord ;
  CLOSE c_empDetails;
END;
```